# Combine multiple Outlook Addins under a single Ribbon UI

Tags: c#, vsto, office-interop, office-addins, ribbonx

I am developing 2 seperate Outlook Addins using the VSTO project type in Visual Studio 2022 (C# .Net 4.7.2) and wish them to appear under the same Ribbon UI.

Is this possible at all?

From the reading I've done I'm not sure it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to use [qualified id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-customui/7c80b304-b2f8-432a-83ee-7f8ec792af0c) to identify the shared items (such as tabs) in your XML (and use the same "qualified id" in both add-ins). Note `idQ` instead of `id`:

```
<tab idQ="mycompany:SharedTab" label="Shared Tab">
```

I don't think Visual Studio ribbon designer supports this (?), so you may need to go with XML directly (click the "Extract Ribbon XML" and then follow the instructions to switch to plain XML ribbon definition)